# Skype Issue writing (New and Old Version)

Tags: 14.04, skype

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Skype (Lastest Version)

I'm not sure why this is happening, but It happened also in old Skype versions. I use SKype at work and usually everything works fine, but some times, suddenly, the "keyboard" stop working (just in Skype), and when I try to write it happens allways the same:

1. The first time I press a key (any key) Skype writes an "S"
2. The 4 next times I press any key, Skype ignores them
3. The 4 next times I press any key, the key is written

After the 3rd step it goes to the first again, and again. I usually copy the text from my editor and paste to avoid this, but I don't know why this happens and none of my mates has this issue.

- Does anybody know something about this issue?

**Info:** This only happens when I'm writing on Skype, so it's not an issue of the keyboard